# Updated index and css font not changing

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, fonts

No matter what I try, I can't get this font to change.

I've gotten the google font url and inserted the code into my index.php

and this is my custom css:

```
fiddle: 1963jety
```

It is still showing as arial font.

Comment: Can you link or paste your code please?

Comment: thats the jsfiddle link^ i used the insert code button in post but it didnt work.

Comment: if it's this http://jsfiddle.net/1963jety/ there is no html at all.

Comment: Ok, try removing the quotes around the font names and make sure you are loading the fonts and using the correct names for the fonts.

Comment: added html to the fiddle. link is at the very bottom. and google itself says to use the quotes. Instructions: Add the font name to your CSS styles just as you'd do normally with any other font.

Example:

h1 { font-family: ‘Metrophobic’, Arial, serif; font-weight: 400; }

Comment: In your `index.php` file, is your google fonts `link` tag above the CSS `link` tag?

Comment: according to [this link](http://tomgurney.co.uk/skills/css/web-fonts/) Fjalla One is a google font, can you confirm you have the link to get the font correct or you have downloaded the font file

Comment: no, but its the same one at breitbart.com andi can load it fine there

Comment: and i dont see any css related code in my index,php

Comment: Please can you edit the question to include links to both CSS and HTML as well as the link to the font you wish to include.

Comment: this is the font. https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Fjalla+One. the fiddle in my post is link to css and html

Comment: if your updated jfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/1963jety/1/ i should point out that you "html" is useless as PHP does not work in jsfiddle and as such none of the HTML we need is appearing

Comment: im sorry. try this. db2d1r0y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `font-weight: 400` because Fjalla One is only 400 Normal.

Comment: CrabLeg i added that, still not working. and my custom css is fine - all taken from main themes default sheet. lukas changed my font weight to 400 still didnt work

Comment: When I am looking at your "code" on JSFiddle, you have some style in HTML, which says that all headings should be Open Sans.

Comment: Is that something that can be changed?

Comment: Is this your site - [link](http://www.offtopicpolitics.com) ? Because the code on JSFiddle is from there, but the site uses "Roboto" font, so I am quite confused...

Comment: yea try clicking an article. i just noticed the font works everywhere but home page

Comment: OK, so finally - change there Roboto on Fjalla One:
`/* Links */
a {
 color: #231F20;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
 outline: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.14s ease 0s; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.14s ease 0s; 
   -o-transition: all 0.14s ease 0s; 
 }`

Comment: NB: would I be right in saying this is a result of my suggestion? If so, please check you are loading the CSS file on the home page and no subsequent file or inline styling is changing this.

Comment: yea, it worked friend. made your post an answer. may i trouble you for one more thing and tell me where i can change the style for the homepage? its already in my style sheet but only changing subsequent pages.

Comment: In your "Custom CSS" there is `/* Links */
a {
 color: #231F20;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
 outline: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.14s ease 0s; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.14s ease 0s; 
   -o-transition: all 0.14s ease 0s; 
 }` 
and you have to change there "Roboto" on "Fjalla One". That skould solve your problem with homepage.

Comment: That did not change it. im talking specifically about the font on the home page not working. like the article titles, excerpts, everything

Comment: It works when I change it using inspector. When I reload your page there is still "Roboto", so I do not know where or what you have changed.

Comment: if i inspect element on an article title it says .entry-header. i have added font family below that in css. i have also added it to H1-H6 and the body content

Comment: OK, again. You posted there the CSS part with your `/* Headings */` customization. In the same CSS file, where I found it, you have `/* Links */` customization just under that. And there you have to change 'Roboto' on 'Fjalla One'. That is all. Do not add anything anywhere, just change this.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I need to see your code. If it's not updating, something is probably wrong with your css code. It may not be written correctly.

Comment: The OP has included a link (of sorts) to the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Include this code in your CSS file:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One);
```

Which will import the font, then:

```
h1{
      font-family: Fjalla One;
}
```

Comment: tried that didnt work

Comment: Is anything changing? What do you see? Please try to be more helpful otherwise we can't assist!

Comment: no - nothing changed. font remains the same.

Comment: oh, you know what, it load on this page http://www.offtopicpolitics.com/trump-gearing-up-for-general-election/. but not the home page

Comment: I'd really need to see your code... It sounds like you need to look at CSS hierarchy and see what's overriding your custom module.

Comment: i got it! yea something was overriding it. thx alot man big help